# How to create an XML root/prolog comment using PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-comments

I'm trying to add a root comment to an XML file that doesn't have one. I'm close, but can't get it in the root/prolog area and instead can only get it injected after the first element.

```
(preloading [xml]$UpdatenuspecFile=somefile.nuspec)
```

What seems logical to me to work would be:

```
 $UpdatednuspecFile.'#comment' = "test"
```

But this results in:

```
Cannot set "#comment" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.
At line:1 char:1
+ $UpdatednuspecFile.'#comment' = "test"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : XmlNodeSetRestrictionsMoreThanOneNode
```

Some (no, a LOT) of Googlefu got me close using:

```
$XMLComment="This is my comment"
$UpdatednuspecFile = [xml]([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(file.nuspec))
$Comment = $UpdatednuspecFile.CreateComment($XMLComment)
$UpdatednuspecFile.DocumentElement.InsertBefore($Comment,$UpatednuspecFile.DocumentElement)
```

I've tried many variations of above such as using `InsertBefore` and `InserAfter` for `$UpatednuspecFile.DocumentElement`, `$UpatednuspecFile`, `$UpatednuspecFile.FirstNode`, `$UpatednuspecFile.xml`, `$UpatednuspecFile.package`, etc etc.

And can't get it to show up immediately after the XML declaration; i.e. line 2.

Instead my comment always shows up inside the first element (package) at the beginning or at the bottom of it.

and displayable (depending on method above) via `$UpdatednuspecFile.package.'#comment'`

Expected result would be to insert and be displayable for 
`$UpdatednuspecFile.'#comment"` to show `$XMLComment`

Comment: `$x.InsertAfter( $x.CreateComment( 'zero pos comment'), $x.FirstChild)` where `$x` is a placeholder for `$UpdatednuspecFile`

Comment: I just tried it and it worked flawlessly. Thank you Jose!